# How to use Visual Studio Macros at compile time in a c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I would like my code to behave differently at compile time by using the configuration parameter.

Something like the sample code below.
I need my project to include different headers in each configuration.

```
#if $(Configuration) == "my_csutom_config"
#include "my_custom_header.h"
#elif
#include "std_header.h"
#endif
```

Comment: You can't do that. I think the only way to accomplish it is to add configuration-specific preprocessor definitions. (Or possibly by tweaking the vcxproj file, but that's opening a truckful of worm cans.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it cannot be done as I wanted but through an indirect step:

In project Properties-> configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor I can simply define a preprocessor variable for each configuration and then use that preprocessor variable as I wanted.